# .Net Framework Data Provider May Not Be Installed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET website created in VS 2010 which is using the MVC3 (Razor) and Entity Framework and MSSQL database. The project runs fine on my machine, however when I publish and upload to my host I get the error:

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

Now I believe that I have added all required DLLs to my /bin folder. This is my connection string in the web.config file:

**Connection String**

```
    <add name="WhimsicalFurnishingEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.WhimsicalFurnishingModel.csdl|res://*/App_Code.WhimsicalFurnishingModel.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.WhimsicalFurnishingModel.msl;
     provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
     provider connection string=&quot;
      data source=localhost\sqlexpress;
      Initial Catalog=DBNAME;
      integrated security=True;
      User ID=DBUSER;
      Password=DBPASSWORD;
      user instance=True;
      multipleactiveresultsets=True;
      App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have read that you might need to add another connection string just for the database SQL Client and I have tried:

**What I Have Tried**

```
    <add name="WhimsicalFurnishingMembership"
    connectionString="data source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=false;User ID=DBUSER;Password=DBPASSWORD;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

However the same error persists. This is the exact error that I am getting from Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may    not be installed.
]
System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +1434271
WebMatrix.Data.DbProviderFactoryWrapper.CreateConnection(String connectionString) +64
WebMatrix.Data.<>c__DisplayClass15.<OpenConnectionStringInternal>b__14() +16
WebMatrix.Data.Database.get_Connection() +19
WebMatrix.Data.Database.EnsureConnectionOpen() +12
WebMatrix.Data.<QueryInternal>d__0.MoveNext() +71
System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4231764
WebMatrix.Data.Database.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] args) +103
WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CheckTableExists(Database db, String tableName) +59
WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateTablesIfNeeded() +55
WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeMembershipProvider(SimpleMembershipProvider sMembership, DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean createTables) +73
WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeProviders(DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +51
WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(String connectionStringName, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +51
ASP._Page__AppStart_cshtml.Execute() in ******\wwwroot\_AppStart.cshtml:3
System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.<ExecuteInternal>b__3() +65
System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.<GetSafeExecuteStartPageThunk>b__a(Action action) +7
System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteInternal() +78
System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteStartPageInternal(HttpApplication application, Action`1 monitorFile, Func`2 fileExists, Func`2 createInstance, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions) +202
System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteStartPage(HttpApplication application, Action`1 monitorFile, Func`2 fileExists, Func`2 createInstance, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions) +41

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.]
System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteStartPage(HttpApplication application, Action`1 monitorFile, Func`2 fileExists, Func`2 createInstance, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions) +88
System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteStartPage(HttpApplication application) +287
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.StartApplication(HttpApplication application, Action`1 executeStartPage, EventHandler applicationStart) +113
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.StartApplication(HttpApplication application) +71
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application) +217
System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +517
System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +194
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +253

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9090876
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +256
```

Is there another way I can try to debug this? Am I missing anything that must be included in my web.config or _AppStart.cshtml file?

Thank You

Comment: This is definitely not ASP Classic.  Retagged.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, except mine is with Oracle instead of SQL Server.  I have not found anything yet, but are you using a different data provider than what is in the .NET framework?  My thread is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544673/cannot-deploy-mvc-3-project-with-entity-framework-4-3-1-and-oracle-odac