# Deploying MVC/Entity Framework application using Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

One of my colleagues needs an application deployed on a web server. However, the application uses MVC and Entity framework (which are both new technologies for me.)

I have done a straight 'bin copy' deployment. Part of the application seems to function properly, but other parts are not. I believe the application is failing when accessing the database.

Here are the application particulars:
- Visual Studio 2010
- MVC 4
- Entity Framework 5
- Database being accessed: Oracle 11gR1

The machine the application is being deployed on:
- Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7
- An existing Oracle 11.2.0 full client (for use with other applications on the server)

My question: Am I doing this right? Is it necessary to do a separate install of ODAC? And if I do, will it mess up my existing Oracle 11 client?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to **install ODAC components on the server.**

Please check below link for more info.

[Cannot Deploy MVC Project with Entity Framework and Oracle ODAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544673/cannot-deploy-mvc-3-project-with-entity-framework-4-3-1-and-oracle-odac)

Comment: I am concerned about interfering with the existing Oracle 11 client... I have installed ODAC but it seems to mess up existing applicatons. Do I need to remove the existing client before installing ODAC? Install Odac in the same directory as the previous client?

Comment: @segnosaur Yep, best thing is removed existing client, before installing ODAC. Check that and let me know.